# Change on Brace Highlight Style does not take effect on Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I use notepad++ to do debugging of complex nests of conditions.
So when I tried changing the styling of the Brace Highlight Style to a more louder color, i was confused why it wasn't taking effect.

I took this advice from the github [site](https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/issues/2865).
So I made global style the same as with the Brace Highlight Style, but still same effect.

Tried restarting notepad++ and still the same.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out, you need to disable the **Enable global foreground color** and **Enable global background color** options off:

go to *Menu > Style Configurator > Global Styles > Global override*

for it to take effect.

Cheers!